# How to find the list of tables which has new set of records impacted in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on exporting data from one environment to another environment. I want to select the list of tables which has new set of records either inserted or modified.

Database has around 200 tables and only if 10 table records are impacted since yesterday, i want to filter only those tables. Some of these tables does not have **createdate** table column. It is harder to identify the record difference based on plain select query to the table.

How to find the list of tables which has new set of records impacted in SQL?
And if possible only those newly impacted records from the identified tables.

I tried with this query, however this query is not returning actual tables.

```
select * from sysobjects where id in (
select object_id
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE last_user_update > getdate() - 1 )
```

Comment: Finding only "new" records this way is impossible; SQL Server does not track data motion if you don't use things like auditing. `dm_db_index_usage_stats` will work as a rough indicator of any updates whatsoever, though (provided the server is not turned off and the database is not detached). If this isn't returning any tables, consider the possibility that they haven't actually seen any new data.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  thank you .. is there a logically way of identifying the newly impacted records.. , i will have to identify the data from UAT and then move it to Prod ..  i need to know the tables and its records.. i will not be able to migrate the database directly to prod ..

Comment: Without a timestamp column, there is inherently no efficient way of doing this. Alternatives include creating triggers on all the tables you're interested in, or using replication. If these are not available, you would need to do things like take a checksum of the rows, store that somewhere, then compare checksums against old values to see what's new. If tables have unique, incrementing IDs you can use those to identify new rows, but that still doesn't solve the problem of updates. There are various (expensive) third party tools that claim to help with such things, but that's off topic for SO.

Comment: I agree with you, when we plan to move the data from UAT to Prod; we can do so only if we are 100% sure on the list of records..  in the current scenario.. i guess it is not possible for me to identify the list of tables and move the data..

Answer (score 1):

If you've not got a timestamp or something to identify newly changed records such as auditing, utilising triggers or [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) enabled on those tables, it's quiet impossible to do.

However, reading your scenario is it not possible to ignore what has changed or been modified and just simply export those 200 tables from one environment to the other and override it on the destination location?

If not, then you might be only interested in comparing data rather than identifying newly changed records to identify which tables did not match. You can do that using [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

See below example of comparing two databases with the same table names and schema creating a dynamic SQL statement column using EXCEPT from both databases on the fly and running them in a while loop; inserting each table name that was effected into a temp table.

```
DECLARE @Counter AS INT
    ,   @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CompareRecords') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CompareRecords
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TablesNotMatched') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TablesNotMatched
CREATE TABLE #TablesNotMatched (ObjectName NVARCHAR(200))

SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNr
    ,   t.TABLE_CATALOG
    ,   t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,   t.TABLE_NAME
    ,   Query =     'IF' +  CHAR(13)
                +   '(' + CHAR(13)
                +   '   SELECT' + CHAR(13)
                +   '       COUNT(*) + 1' + CHAR(13)
                +   '   FROM' + CHAR(13)
                +   '   (' + CHAR(13)
                +   '       SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME, '''''') + ' AS TableName, * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME) + CHAR(13)
                +   '       EXCEPT' + CHAR(13)
                +   '       SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME, '''''') + ' AS TableName, * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t2.TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME) + CHAR(13)
                +   '   ) AS sq' + CHAR(13)
                +   ') > 1' + CHAR(13)
                +   'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME), '''''') + ' AS TableNameRecordsNotMatched'
    INTO #CompareRecords
FROM <UAT_DATABASE>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
LEFT JOIN <PROD_DATABASE>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t2 ON    t.TABLE_SCHEMA = t2.TABLE_SCHEMA 
                                                            AND t.TABLE_NAME = t2.TABLE_NAME

WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'


SET @Counter = (SELECT MAX(RowNr) FROM #CompareRecords)

WHILE @Counter > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Query = (SELECT cr.Query FROM #CompareRecords AS cr WHERE cr.RowNr = @Counter)
        INSERT INTO #TablesNotMatched
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
        SET @Counter = @Counter - 1
    END

SELECT
        *
FROM #TablesNotMatched
```

---

Note when using EXCEPT both tables have to have the exact same column count and type.

I hope this slightly helps.

Comment: thank you.. I have used Except in the past. I forgot about Except syntax. Yes, i agree with you Except syntax will be very helpful. Some tables which has metadata .. which doesn't change often does not have the createdate field. Metadata don't change often, however they are added .. every now and then .. , thanks for the details.. i will test the scenario..